# Sending data to serial with pyserial - Work on Razor 9DOF IMU

Tags: python, linux, arduino, pyserial

I'm currently workng on a **IMU Razor 9DOF**
I can read data from it by reading */dev/ttyUSB0*. (default mode is YPR = angles of the IMU)
I can also change the data i'm receiving by sending **#ot** or **#osrt** to the IMU via the Arduino's Serial Monitor.

So I'm trying to write a code in Python3 to do both reading and changing mode via the same interface (and also using python3 to process the data).
Here are my issues:
**1.** I am using pyserial to read data from the port. Here is my code:

```
    from serial import *
    usb = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600)
    while True:
       usb.readline()

    print()
```

When I try to run this code via python console it runs perfectly, but when I try doing it from the script (python3 mycode.py) it doesn't work.
I don't understand why.

**2.** I try to change the mode by sending the command '#osrt' by using

```
    usb.write(byte("#osrt", "utf8"))
```

but it only returns the length of data written without changing the mode.

Thank You For Your Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended when using `readline` you set a timeout. readline will wait until a `\n` is received.

```
from serial import *
    usb = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600)
    usb.timeout = 1
    while True:
       print(usb.readline()) # you need to print what you are reading in the script
```

Comment: Thank You!
I found the solution for my second issue: i wasn't reading enough lines to see the change on data.